# Vim iskeyword being reset

Tags: vim

I have this problem where my iskeyword is getting reset to include '.'.  It's very annoying, and I've tried to solve the problem by putting in my vimrc:

```
set iskeyword-=.
```

I've also tried for language-specific files:

```
au FileType javascript setl sw=2 sts=2 et isk-=.
```

I am using SPF-13, so I know there is a lot going on under the hood. I am doing this in my .vimrc.local, and it should be getting set last.

Ultimately, my question is two-fold:

1. Is there some way I can set this to make sure it isn't reset?
2. Is there some way I can debug vim to determine where this option is getting reset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out where from the option was last set with `:verbose set iskeyword` (see `:help :verbose-cmd`). I'm not aware of a way to lock an option to prevent future changes, and even if there is a way it is probably not what you want. Once you find out where from the option was last set you can reason about it, why it is being changed, and address the specific problem more appropriately.